# Where is sprite lit material in unity?

Tags: reactjs, unity-game-engine, light, vision, glow

I know that this is a very basic question but I really need some help in that I want to put the material of my BackGround as a sprite lit default material so it can react to light but I'm not finding it in the materials even when I disable the vision icon at the top right it just doesn't show up any help, please?
And again sorry for the basic question <3

Comment: I don't think there is, you would need to use normal lit material with Quad or Plane mesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(It's a bit difficult to understand your question, so hopefully this helps)
If you're using legacy, create a new material. Then in the drop down for shader type, select Sprites->Diffuse. Drag that on to your sprite's material box.

Comment: Thx I'll try it

Comment: Cool, if you found it helpful, mark this as  an answer, and i'll update it a bit